# Linux Fortran OpenMP - accessing global variables from a subroutine called from an OpenMP task

Tags: linux, fortran, openmp, intel-fortran

Is it legal/valid to access program global variables from an internal subroutine called from an OpenMP task?

ifort 2021.7.0 20220726 doesn't report an error, but appears to produce random results depending on compiler options.  Example:

```
program test1
  implicit none
  integer :: i, j, g
  g = 42
  !$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED)
     !$OMP SINGLE
        i = 0
        j = 1
        do while (j < 60)
           i = i + 1
           !$OMP TASK DEFAULT(SHARED) FIRSTPRIVATE(i,j)
              call sub(i,j)
           !$OMP END TASK
           j = j + j
        end do
     !$OMP END SINGLE
  !$OMP END PARALLEL
  stop

contains

  subroutine sub(i,j)
    implicit none
    integer i,j
    !$OMP CRITICAL(unit6)
       write(6,*) i,j,g
    !$OMP END CRITICAL(unit6)
  end subroutine sub

end program test1
```

Compiled with:  ifort -o test1 test1.f90 -qopenmp -warn all -check all

Expected result:

```
           5          16          42
           4           8          42
           6          32          42
           3           4          42
           2           2          42
           1           1          42
```

Obtained result:

```
           2           2  -858993460
           5          16  -858993460
           4           8  -858993460
           6          32  -858993460
           1           1  -858993460
           3           4  -858993460
```

Note: the order of output lines doesn't matter --- just the number in the third column should be 42.

Different unexpected results are obtained by changing compiler options.  For example, with "ifort -o test1 test1.f90 -qopenmp -warn all -O0", the third column is 256 and with "ifort -o test1 test1.f90 -qopenmp -O0" it is -740818552.

Of course g could be passed to sub() as an argument, but the program I'm assisting with working on has dozens of shared global variables (that don't change in the parallel part) and subroutine calls go several layers deep.

Thanks, Peter McGavin.

Comment: It looks like a bug at first glance. It works with gfortran.

Comment: Using global variables in `contains` routines is usually a bad idea. Can you put those variables in a module?

Comment: Global variables are usually a bad idea full stop, especially when parallelism is involved. I'm not sure modules are massively better than via host association.

Comment: Second the compiler bug theory - this works for me with gfortrans 9.4.0 and 10.3.0, ifort 2021.6.0 20220226 and  ifx 2022.1.0 20220316 . What version of ifort are you using? Does it work if you download the latest and possibly greatest?

Comment: Ian, I tested with ifort versions 2021.2.0 20210228 and 2021.7.0 20220726, the latter included in Intel's latest oneAPI HPC Toolkit downloaded yesterday.  The example I posted works OK with just "-qopenmp" but fails when "-check all" or "-O0" are added.  More complex examples I tried fail with just "-qopenmp".

Comment: OK - I can repeat that, without -O0 or -check all it works, with them it gives the wrong answer. I still think it is a compiler bug - I would report to Intel

Comment: Interestingly `ifort -qopenmp -check all,nostack ompgl.f90` works which to me strongly suggests that it is a compiler bug associated `-check stack` - hopefully this also gives a partial workaround

Comment: Thanks Ian.  Actually I tried posting to the the Intel Fortran Forum before posting here, but my message was immediately marked as spam and the moderator did not respond to my message.  I don't know how else to report a compiler bug to Intel.

Comment: That's ... disappointing. Maybe Steve Lionel who is sometimes seen here can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the oneAPI compiler package 2022.2 or 2022.3.

```
/iusers/xtian/temp$ ifx -qopenmp  jimtest.f90
/iusers/xtian/temp$ ./a.out
           2           2          42
           1           1          42
           3           4          42
           5          16          42
           4           8          42
           6          32          42
```

Comment: 2022.3 Release is externally available https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/toolkits.html

Comment: Note that the question uses ifort, not ifx. Does the problem exist in older versions of ifx? Does it exist in the new version of ifort?

Comment: ifx version 2022.2.0 20220730 fails with the "-check all", "-check stack" or "-O0" option.  I'm about to try 2022.3.

Comment: @xtian One of the points of the question is it works with earlier versions ifort or ifx if compiled as you suggest, but fails if you add the flags listed above by Peter. Please see my comments below the question

Comment: The ifort and ifx compilers in the 2022.3 HPC pack also fail for me with any of the "-check all", "-check stack" or "-O0" options.  They are ifort 2021.7.0 20220726 and ifx 2022.2.0 20220730

Comment: For -check all, -cheack stack support, please try 2022.3. Thanks.

Comment: If you still see fails, file a JIRA report by contacting our compiler support team. We will look into that. Thanks.

Comment: xtian, I am using the 2022.3 HPC pack.  The Fortran compilers in the 2022.3 HPC pack are ifort 2021.7.0 20220726 and ifx 2022.2.0 20220730.  I don't know how to get any higher numbered compilers.

Comment: Filing a JIRA report by contacting the Intel compiler support team appears to require a paid subscription.  In any case, my post to the Intel Fortran Forum has been accepted now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Added the link to the Intel support. 
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/support.html#gs.epmz9v

Comment: https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/bd-p/fortran-compiler  This link has more Fortran related information. Thanks.